# Import Excel Data to Mongodb using Java

Tags: java, json, excel, mongodb, apache-poi

Tried Importing Excel Data to Mongo db in the Following Document Format

```
[
{"productId":"",
"programeName":"",
"programeThumbImageURL":"",
"programeURL":"",
"programEditors":["editor1","editor2"],
"programChapters":[
{
"chapterName":"chapter1",
"authorNames":["authorName1","authorname2"]
},
{"chapterName":"chapter2"},
"authorNames":["authorName1","authorName2"]
}
,...
]},...]
```

There are many products in the Excel with with chapterNames has multiple authors. following is the code which tried executing and i could do inserting data. But the i couldn't merge the authorNames corresponding to a particular chapterName as above. So currently there are programChapters array contains objects as duplicated chapterNames. Following code shows my experiment towards this.

```
private static XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String[] programs = {"programName1","programName2","programName3","programName4",...};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
DB db = mongo.getDB("dbName");

DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("programsCollection");

File myFile =
    new File("dsm_article_author_details.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile); // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0); // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator(); // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
for (String program : programs) {
  String programName = "";
  String chapterName = "";
  String authorName = "";

  BasicDBObject product = new BasicDBObject();

  BasicDBList programChaptersList = new BasicDBList();
  // For Each Row , Create Chapters Object here

  for (int i = 0; i <= mySheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) { // points to the starting of excel i.e
                                                       // excel first row
    Row row = (Row) mySheet.getRow(i); // sheet number
    System.out.println("Row is :" + row.getRowNum());

    BasicDBObject programChapters = new BasicDBObject();
    if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
      programName = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
      System.out.println("programName : " + programName);
    }

    if (row.getCell(1).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
      chapterName = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().replaceAll("\n", "");
      System.out.println("chapterName : " + chapterName);
    }

    if (row.getCell(2).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
      authorName = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
      System.out.println("authorName : " + authorName);
    }

    List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();

    programChapters.put("chapterName", chapterName);

    authors.add(authorName);
    programChapters.put("authorName", authors);

    if (programName.trim().equals(program.trim())) {
      programChaptersList.add(programChapters);
    }
  }

  product.put("programName", program);
  product.put("programThumbImageURL", "");
  product.put("programeURL", "");
  product.put("programChapters", programChaptersList);

  collection.insert(product);
  System.out.println("*#*#*#*#*#");
}
}
```

I hope this is the part went wrong. Need to store all chapterNames in an array and compare with each upcoming value and according to that create new objects and store it in a list

```
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();

programChapters.put("chapterName", chapterName);

authors.add(authorName);
programChapters.put("authorName", authors);
```

Can someone suggest me, available solutions :-)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is the part went wrong. Need to store all chapterNames in an array and compare with each upcoming value and according to that create new objects and store it in a list

```
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();

programChapters.put("chapterName", chapterName);

authors.add(authorName);
programChapters.put("authorName", authors);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an extension of your question?

Comment: its just an extension

Comment: Don't post updates/clarifications to your question as answers! You should instead just edit your question with the extra details. Please see the help center if you're new / struggling to use the site